# How to correctly write regex to findstr for cmd?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, printing, regex, findstr

I am trying to only print UUID in windows and running following command:

```
wmic csproduct get uuid | findstr /R “[a-zA-Z0-9]{5}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{5}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{5}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{5}”
```

Above command returns empty string.

If I do following:

```
wmic csproduct get uuid
```

It'd print following:

> UUID
>
> uuid-example-9596-dj9v

I am trying to only print only last line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, `findstr` regexes are very basic, it doesn't support quantifier like `{5}`.

You have to write *in extenso*:

`[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]-[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]-[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]-[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]`

and I recommend to use word boundaries:

`\<[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]-[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]-[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]-[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]\>`

You can use alternatives, see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/87350/372239